# Copy shape from hidden sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to do this without the .Select parts? This works fine until I hide the sheet "Sparade värden".

```
    Sheets("Sparade värden").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Autoskala")).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Mätplan").Select
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Autoskala")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Autoskala").IncrementLeft 19
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Autoskala").IncrementTop -18
```

I've tried this but then I get an error:

```
    Sheets("Sparade värden").Shapes.Range(Array("Autoskala")).Copy
    Sheets("Mätplan").Range("A6").Paste
    Sheets("Mätplan").Shapes.Range(Array("Autoskala")).Select
    Sheets("Mätplan").Shapes("Autoskala").IncrementLeft 19
    Sheets("Mätplan").Shapes("Autoskala").IncrementTop -18
```

The error I get:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error message and on what line?

Comment: @dbmitch sorry, I've updated the post with the error and the line is "Sheets("Sparade värden").Shapes.Range(Array("Autoskala")).Copy"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following . . .

```
Sheets("Sparade värden").Shapes("Autoskala").Copy

With Sheets("Mätplan")
    .Paste .Range("A6")
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .IncrementLeft 19
        .IncrementTop -18
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! It almost works. It's just the Increment that does not for some reason.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works just fine, no errors.  I even tested it with both sheets hidden and, again, no errors.

Comment: Which error does it give you?

Comment: I don't get any errors but it does not move from its starting position

Comment: The Increment doesn't work for some reason

Comment: Do you have any error handling that might be hiding errors?  Maybe somewhere in your code you have  `On Error GoTo` or `On Error Resume Next`?  If so, comment it out or  temporarily remove that line from your code, run it again, and see if any errors pop up.